# how to change font in the webview app android

Tags: java, android, css, fonts

Hi guys I want to change the font inside the application. Is there a way to add the font I want?

```
String mimeType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    String encoding = "utf-8";
    String htmlText = str_desc;
    String text = "<html><head>"
            + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #525252;}"
            + "</style></head>"
            + "<body>"
            + htmlText
            + "</body></html>";

    news_desc.loadData(text, mimeType, encoding);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the css for `body`?

Comment: Yes, but maybe I did not do the right way. Can you give me the way?

Comment: `body{color:#525252; font:«whatever font you want here»;}`

Comment: The method did not work with me. I use a font called "jf-flat" which is Courier New. Path to the assets / fonts folder. Can you write me the code to change the font because I am tired and tried all the methods

Comment: 1) "did not work" is not good enough; we need to know what happened: error messages, unexpected results etc. 2) "jf-flat" is not "Courier New", so is it the one or the other? 3) We are not a code writing service. 4) Show us what you tried. The exact code, the resulting HTML (in the browser), also the make and version of the browser, operating system, etc.

Comment: I am sorry it is not a professional word but the problem I do not know is responsible for changing the font type of the script or from the application